# Is there a plugin to show Veracode results in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, build, veracode

We currently run Veracode scans after our builds in Jenkins.  I have been unable to find a way to display the results from these scans so that our team has a good snapshot view in Jenkins.  Ideally, we would like to show statistics, such as the number of High vulnerabilities, Medium vulnerabilities, etc.  At the very least, it would be good to be able to allow a logged-in user to download the report as an artifact of the build.

Answer (score 0):

The current Veracode Jenkins plugin does not display results, only a pass or fail (if the option to wait for results is selected).

Please feel free to contact me at my Twitter handle (in my profile) if you would like to discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try SCA (Software compsition Analysis) [https://docs.veracode.com/r/yWEmzLVoSzK6HlP~GSch2w/hCnPFxWkKZlWsP~JHsmYDg](https://docs.veracode.com/r/yWEmzLVoSzK6HlP%7EGSch2w/hCnPFxWkKZlWsP%7EJHsmYDg)

and the result will display in the consol output

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).